# Is it halachically permissible for Jews to celebrate Kwanzaa?

Tags: non-jewish-holidays, contemporary-halacha

Unlike Christmas, Kwanzaa does not seem to be associated with any particular non-Jewish religion.

As such, I am curious: is it still considered an idolatrous holiday? Does it fall under the category of copying heathen customs? Is it completely forbidden? Partially forbidden? Partially permitted? Completely permitted?

What would the Jewish approach to Kwanzaa be?

Comment: Kwanzaa was designed to be a cultural festival that anyone can partake in, regardless of religious/cultural affiliation.  It's a time that promotes family principles, honoring the elders, teaching the youth how to be accountable.  The emphasis is on unity, love for one another, belief that no matter where you or your community is that there is always redemption, using your talents/gifts for the betterment of humanity, and seeing your fellow man (not limit to your community) as an extension as yourself.

Comment: Kwanzaa was invented by [this guy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maulana_Karenga). Given what he's done in his life, not sure how proper it would be to celebrate it...